# Alienware x15 R2 black screen. Corrupt UEFI?

Tags: laptop-repair

My ~2 years old Alienware x15 R2 stopped working. The motherboard is LA-L611. Power light and keyboard turn on, power light flashes 2x red and 3x blue, screen stays black.

Dell error codes indicates this is the error

> 2,3 No memory or Random-Access Memory (RAM) detected

After disassembling and removing the battery after discharging any static electricity by holding the power button without the power cable connected, symptom persists.

After removing the motherboard and disconnecting all cables, keeping only the PSU and display cables connected, it powered on and showed the UEFI ("BIOS") recovery screen.

However, since USB and keyboard weren't connected I couldn't perform the reset. So, after shutting down the system and reconnecting the keyboard, the system stays with a black screen. Then I removed all cables again, keeping only display and power as before, and the screen is still black and not even going into UEFI recovery no matter how many times I tried.

I couldn't find any schematics of the board to try to diagnose it further. I was thinking about reprogramming the firmware with my programming tool but I noticed there are around 3 or 4 Winbound chips and I am not certain which one is actually the main UEFI one or if I could find a working dump for this system.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: If the motherboard doesn't find the RAM, how are you going to "fix" this in the BIOS? Concentrate on the physical RAM instead.

Comment: The RAM is soldered on the mainboard, this is the reason I am focusing on the bios as of now, I do not want to reflow the ram just for the sake of it

Comment: The BIOS has a diagnostic tool to test the ram?

Comment: Hello I cannot reach diagnostic tool, it's only black screen

Comment: Run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for a long time, preferably even over-night.

Comment: I don't think u get it , as I said it's not turning on